Area in which retarded potential is non-zero if $\vec{j}(\vec{v},s)$ is non-zero only for $|\vec{v}|< \epsilon \wedge s>0$
I've encountered a type of problem I have never seen before, and I would like to know if my attempt at solving it is right or even just on the right track.
The Problem:

The retarded vector-potential is $$\vec{A}_\mu
(\vec{x},t)=\frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \mathrm{d}^3 y \frac{\vec{j}\left(\vec{y}, t-
\dfrac{||x-y||}{c}\right)}{||x-y||}$$
Now let $\vec{j}(\vec{v},s)$ be non-zero only for $|\vec{v}|< \epsilon \wedge s>0$. Sketch the area $(x,t)$ on which $A$ is non-zero.

My attempt at a solution:
So that $\vec{A}_\mu (\vec{x},t) \neq 0,  \vec{j}\left(\vec{y}, t- \dfrac{||x-y||}{c}\right)$ must not be equal to zero for all $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, that means
$$\text{for set x and t} \space \space : \exists \vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^3 : |\vec{y}|< \epsilon \wedge t-\frac{||x-y||}{c}>0.$$
Right off the bat, we can reduce ourselves to just looking at $|\vec{y}| < \epsilon$ since $j$ is automatically zero if the left argument has a magnitude bigger than $\epsilon$. According to the triangle inequality:
$$|x-y| \leq |x|+|y| \leq |x| + \epsilon.$$
This can be manipulated to
$$-|x-y| \geq -|x| - \epsilon$$
$$t-\frac{|x-y|}{c} \geq t- \frac{|x|}{c} - \frac{\epsilon}{c}.$$
If we set this lower bound $t- \dfrac{|x|}{c} - \dfrac{\epsilon}{c} > 0$, $t-\dfrac{|x-y|}{c} > 0$ will certainly hold as well:
$$t- \frac{|x|}{c} > \frac{\epsilon}{c}. $$
This is the inside of a light cone that has been shifted up by $\dfrac{\epsilon}{c}$, I think.
